# How to find which value of the regex pattern the string is matched?

Tags: c#, regex, match

Is there a way to find the exact value of the pattern which the string I am testing is matched.If I had this regular expression

```
^[a-z]((es)|(ing)|(s))$
```

I like the result to looks like the string ends with es or string ends with ing etc,deppending on the pattern that the string is matched using C#?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you include an example?

Comment: Do you want to get a list of matches in the string with this regex?

Comment: Do you mean you want a plain English description of the regular expression to be generated?

Comment: I think what he's trying to say is that he wants to get the actual value of the matched capture group to be returned. For example, if he runs the expression against "yes", he wants to capture the "es" and if he runs it against "king" he wants to capture "ing".

Comment: The comment of Mattias Buelens was my point

Answer (score 1):

[This tool](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) may help you. It lest you write and test regular expressions. A bit a trial and error should get you where you're trying to go.

Comment: Another really handy regex builder that doesn't require download is http://gskinner.com/RegExr/